# PHP it does not work in my modal with semantic UI

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I am trying the Modal with semantic and I put a PHP in my modal but it doesn't work, why?
I know that my modal is generate by the JavaScript and generally this script is meant to return the message that is in my variable message.

script :

```
<?php $message = ""; ?>

<body>
    <button class="ui primary button" type="button" id="openModal">
        apparaitre modal
    </button>
    <form class="ui form modal" method="post">
        <div class="header">
            Modal Title
        </div>
        <div class="image content">
            <div class="image">
                An image can appear on left or an icon
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                A description can appear on the right
                <?php
                    echo $message;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
            <div class="ui button" type="submit" name="val">OK</div>
        </div>
</form>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['val'])) {
        $message = "3 essais restant";
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        $("#openModal").click(function () {
            $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _put a php in my modal but it does work, why?_ Ehh? Why PHP shouldn't work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you would like to have the message in your model?

If so, you need to change your code. Cause the message is still empty. First you set it to nothing and afterwards you fill it. 
So first fill the variable and then display it. Like so:

```
<?php
    $message = "";
    if(isset($_POST['val'])) {
        $message = "3 essais restant";
    }
?>

<body>
<button class="ui primary button" type="button" id="openModal">
    apparaitre modal
</button>
<form class="ui form modal" method="post">
    <div class="header">
        Modal Title
    </div>
    <div class="image content">
        <div class="image">
            An image can appear on left or an icon
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            A description can appear on the right
            <?php
            echo $message;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
        <button class="ui button" type="submit" name="val">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $("#openModal").click(function () {
        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working. If the message is not displayed, then there is no 'val' posted.

Comment: of course it obvious but if i click on my button ok with the name val the variable message = "3 essais restant"

Comment: Well, then i don't understand your problem. Could you be more specific?

Comment: when i click on my button, message is meant changed of void to "3 essais restant"

Comment: but nothings happens

Comment: I updated the anwser. You need a button to sumbit your form.

Comment: i'm var_dump message but nothing

Comment: The code is working here. If you open the model for the second time the message is there.